# find a closed expression for the number of set partitions of the set

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Find a closed expression for the number of set partitions of the set {1, 2, ..., 3n}
into 3 blocks with n elements each. (We don’t care about ordering of the blocks.)

So would the sets be from 1...n, n + 1...2n, 2n +1...3n? What do I do from here?

Comment: How many ways are there of picking the first block? How many elements are there to choose from, and how many do you have to _choose_ (hint hint)?

Comment: Would it be 3 choose 1 (for the block) then 3n choose n (for the elements)?

Comment: Great, so you have $\binom{3n}{n}$ ways of choosing elements for the first block. After that, how many ways of choosing elements for the second block? And finally, what choices will you have left to make for the third block?

Comment: So the second block will be 2n choose n and third block will be n choose n? Then multiply all three?

Comment: @hilh That is close to a correct solution, however that ignores the fact that we don't care which block was which.  Correct the count by dividing by the number of ways in which we could have assigned labels to the groups to "forget" the incorrectly applied importance of which group was which that we had accidentally included by doing it in this way.  That would give $\binom{3n}{n}\binom{2n}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{3!}$ which equals the same as my answer below which avoids the division by symmetry argument used here.

Comment: @hilh It would be useful to study both solutions to understand why they're the same. You can either avoid double-counting with some cleverness as JMoravitz does in his answer, or correct after the fact as s/he pointed out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the blocks must necessarily contain $1$ and $n-1$ additional elements.

Choose what the $n-1$ additional elements that appear along-side the element $1$ in $\binom{3n-1}{n-1}$ ways.

Now, among those $2n$ elements remaining, there will be a unique smallest element left.  That smallest element will be paired with $n-1$ additional elements.  Choose what they were in $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ ways.

The final remaining $n$ elements will form the final part in the partition.

$$\binom{3n-1}{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$$